# Getting Data from a Message Driven Bean into JSF Pages

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I've got a message driven bean that receives JMS messages and I'd like to get some of that data into my JSF components (PrimeFaces) inside those web pages.

I understand getting data from a JSF web page through managed beans and into EJB's, but I'm going the other direction and not clear on this. Not clear on specifically, how to call and pass data to a managed bean for the displayed web page from an EJB.

My guess is this would look something like  ...

(some event) ---> message driven bean ---> managed bean ---> JSF page

Of course the event into the MDB works fine, but only when this JSF web page is being displayed should the managed bean be accepting it's own events so they can be displayed on the web page.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: i dont think you want the mdb to manipulate state of an mb. i think what you want to do is have the mdb trigger a websockets push event that has the browser trigger a request. look into primefaces push showcase and see if this is the func you are after

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And push looks like what I'm after.

Comment: Your comment turns out to be my answer, but as a comment, I can't mark it as the answer (unless you want to repost as an answer).

Comment: Added same as answer + proper link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think you want the mdb to manipulate state of an mb.

i think what you want to do is have the mdb trigger a websockets push event that has the browser trigger a request.

look into primefaces push showcase and see if this is the func you are after

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/facesmessage.jsf